# Adobe Flash and mp3 licence

Tags: flash, licensing, mp3

When I publish a Flash file that contains any sound (such as a WAV file), I can choose the sound compression method (MP3, raw, ADPCM, etc.). My question is about the mp3 compression and it's licence.

Flash gives me the option to compress a WAV file as mp3, but is the licence to use the mp3 format included? I have paid for a Flash licence, does it give the right to use mp3 in my SWF files freely or do I have to pay royalties to someone else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the end user license agreement](http://www.adobe.com/products/eula/third_party/flashmedia/):

> Licensee cannot use the Software for
>   the encoding or decoding of MP3 audio
>   only (.mp3) data on any non-PC device
>   (i.e., mobile phone or set-top box),
>   nor may the MP3 encoders or decoders
>   contained in the Software be used or
>   accessed by any product other than the
>   Software. The **Software may be used
>   for the encoding or decoding of MP3
>   data contained within an SWF or FLV**
>   file, which contains video, picture or
>   other data. Licensee acknowledges that
>   use of the Software for non-PC
>   devices, as described in the
>   prohibitions in this paragraph may
>   require the payment of licensing
>   royalties or other amounts to third
>   parties who may hold intellectual
>   property rights related to the MP3
>   technology and that Adobe has not paid
>   any royalties or other amounts on
>   account of third party intellectual
>   property rights for such use. If
>   Customer requires an MP3 encoder or
>   decoder for such use, **Customer is
>   responsible for obtaining the
>   necessary MP3 technology license**.

IANAL but I think it says that as long as you use the mp3 from inside the flv (or swf) then its free

Comment: neither IANAL; The license is confusing on that point and I'd ask Adobe for clarification. However it seems to be that you can't use Flash to decode mp3s outside SWF and FLV on embedded devices. That's not what you're trying to do.